# Activity restarts unexpectedly

Tags: android

I am writing a trivia game application, where user sequentially gets questions and answer. I use Toast to show user if the answer is correct or not.

First game runs without problem. But when I finish the first game and continue to play second game, a error occurs. After passing some first questions in second game (often 2 or 3 questions), it automatically restarts and I get back from first question. Because of this restart it like I start playing third game.

But the second game still runs behind. Because Toast for the second game still occurs (Toast' message like "Second game - your answer for question number 4 is correct"), that is why I say second game still runs.

Android Monitor don't say any error in logcat. What can be possible reason for this problem?

Comment: An error occurs? That sounds like a crash, perhaps you should look at what is happening. Or add logs to help you figure out what is going on. As it stands this is a very vague description of an issue that you need to dig into to provide clarity on what exactly you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is fixed. The problem was: there are two activities in my app (say it A B), activity B will start A after 10 second (I used CountdownTimer to start A in onFinish()). But B contains a button which start A immediately. When I click the button, activity A starts. But 10 second later B still starts A again.